# BLE data not being recieved when the app is running in background

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy

The below code corresponds to BLE where the central recieves data from peripheral when the app is running in foreground. But when the central is in background and I try to send the data from peripheral the data is not being sent to central.

I have no knowledge on how background activities work in **iOS**. What changes to be included or added to make it work even in background. I have even added Background fetch to background modes in signing capabilities, but it still remains the same. Thanks in advance.

```
 func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {

      if let characteristic = rxCharacteristic {
    

          if let dataa = characteristic.value{
              let ASCIIstring = String(bytes: dataa, encoding: .utf8)// else { return }
              print("dataa \(dataa)...\(ASCIIstring)")
              
          }
          

        let data1 = characteristic.value
        let resultTrimFirst = data1
        guard let resultTrimLast = resultTrimFirst else { return }
      let readValue = String(bytes: resultTrimLast, encoding: .utf8)
          print("readvaluse \(readValue) ")
      NotificationCenter.default.post(name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "Notify"), object: "\((readValue ?? ""))")
      }
  }
```

Comment: You need to enable the Bluetooth central background mode and make sure you are using `notify` from your peripheral. You cannot use polling `read`s